# null on dataAdapter sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Am trying to load values from my sqlite database on android but i keep getting null on dataAdapter. I used this method to load values on many places in my code. But here i keep getting null and i cant find out why. Hoping you can help me people. Am sure this is a small mistake but its been a few days and i cant seem to find it. I get the null error at the very last lines on dataAdapter1 variable. Where ive put the stars.

My database is:

```
public long insertDefaultDistanceUnit(String dUnit, int usedBoolean) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE, dUnit);
    initialValues.put(MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE_BOOLEAN, usedBoolean);
    return db.insert(MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE_UNIT_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public Cursor getAllDistanceUnits() {
    return db.query(MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE_UNIT_TABLE,
            new String[] { MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE }, null, null, null, null,
            null);
}

public Cursor getCurrentDistanceUnit() throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE_UNIT_TABLE,
            new String[] { MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE },
            MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE_BOOLEAN + "='1'", null, null, null, null,
            null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

My settings class that i put values into the table before opening the class i want to load the values:

```
    db.open();
    Cursor c2 = db.getAllDistanceUnits();
    distanceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c2.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            distanceList.add(c2.getString(c2
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE)));
        } while (c2.moveToNext());
    }
    if (distanceList.size() > 0) {
        distanecExist = 1;
    }
    db.close();

    if (distanecExist == 0) {
        currentDistanceUnit = new ArrayList<String>();
        currentDistanceUnit.add("km" + " Kilometers");
        currentDistanceUnit.add("m" + " Miles");
        db.open();
        for (int i = 0; i <= currentDistanceUnit.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                db.insertDefaultDistanceUnit(currentDistanceUnit.get(i)
                        .toString(), 1);
            } else {
                db.insertDefaultDistanceUnit(currentDistanceUnit.get(i)
                        .toString(), 0);
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

and my class that i want to load the values:

```
    currentDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentDistance);
    distanceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distanceSpinner);
    setNewDistanceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setNewDistanceButton);

    db.open();
    Cursor c2 = db.getCurrentDistanceUnit();
    currentDistanceList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String distanceUnit = "";
    if (c2.getCount() == 1) {
        distanceUnit = c2.getString(c2
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE));
    }
    currentDistance.setText(distanceUnit);
    db.close();

    db.open();
    Cursor c1 = db.getAllDistanceUnits();
    currentDistanceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            currentDistanceList.add(c1.getString(c1
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.MY_CURRENT_DISTANCE)));
        } while (c1.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currentDistanceList);
    dataAdapter1
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    distanceSpinner.setAdapter(**dataAdapter1**);
    distanceSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

also here is the logcat errors:

```
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at com.example.mycarfuel.ChangeDistanceActivity.onCreate(ChangeDistanceActivity.java:41)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
02-11 09:33:46.870: E/AndroidRuntime(27105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: true. forgot about that. Its posted

Comment: check your ArrayAdapter context and check where you are adding data to your arraylist currentDistanceList.add and make sure your arraylist is not null.

Comment: where did u declare dataAdapter1

Comment: its a global variable. I didnt mention it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we try to setAdapter(null), there will be no crash and no null pointer exception.
If your crash is on line

```
distanceSpinner.setAdapter(**dataAdapter1**);
```

distanceSpinner is null not your dataAdapter.

Comment: I changed the order of some of the code and now the error directs at this line   currentDistance.setText(distanceUnit);
 I print at the log before setting the text the distanceUnit and there is a value init. But i keep getting null when i setText into currentDistance. My currentDistance is correctly declared. Why would i get null since distanceUnit has values?

Comment: Its not distanceUnit, currentDistance is the culprit. Its the similar error. Check the layout which you have used for setContentView. Does it have ids currentDistance, distanceSpinner etc.

Comment: You are right m8. The problem was in setContentView. Slightly different than it should be and it caused all this trouble. Thank you